# Business Objects Connect "clsid not specified or erroneous" SQL Server 2019

Tags: business-objects, sql-server-2019

We are migrating from Business Objects 4.2 to Business Objects 4.3 and also from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2019. We are also moving from Webi Thick Client to Webi Thin

The 4.3 install is to a fresh server and we have promoted universes from 4.2 to 4.3 via the CMC.

When reports are run on the new server we get the following error:

> The following database error occurred: (CS) "COM Provider CLSID not specified or erroneous" . For information about this error, please refer to SAP Knowledge Base Article 2054721 on the SAP Support Portal. (IES 10901)

I don't have direct access to SAP we have to go via a third party and that third party speaks to SAP... and honestly I have still to find out what the SAP article says.

I can see that the BOBJ connection (4.3 to SQL 2019) is not working:

> OLE DB Provider CLSID not specified or erroneous

but for the life of me I cannot work out the fix. I have downloaded and installed what I feel are the latest MS drivers:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/download-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16 (just in case I am doing this wrong)

and "changed driver" via IDT and also tried to create a new connection. Test Connection fails in both situations.

The .sbo file looks OK to me... but I have reached a stage where I am second guessing myself the whole time... I have not altered them from the default.

I have seen some answers that seem to suggest installing the whole of Management Studio on the BOBJ Server, that feels like overkill and when I looked I am not overly sure I can get this as a downloadable install from MS.

I really don't think I am the first person to have this issue and so I really feel that I am doing something wrong to not find an answer via the internet (or I guess it is telling me I don't understand the answers I am getting).

I have spoken to BOBJ Admin who have 4.3 and SQL Server 2019 and it seems to have just worked for them...

Anyway.... that is a long story long, and while I appreciate that I am obviously missing something (and I suspect it will be something simple) I did want people to understand I have tried. Just to say I am not a BOBJ Admin by trade, but I guess this is also obvious by now :)

Does anybody have any thoughts or things I could try or point me in a direction that I should have probably worked out on my own.

Thanks for reading and have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to 4.3 the Information Design Tool used 32-bit drivers. Now in 4.3, IDT uses 64-bit drivers. Perhaps your BOBJ Admin has the 64-bit driver installed and that is why it worked for them. The BOBJ servers have utilized 64-bit drivers for awhile now, but you should check that too.

If this question get closed before you get this situation resolved repost it [here](https://bobj-board.org/).